# Failed to create bus connection; running command 'timedatectl' had status 1

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2.
In R, I tried to install packages. For example:

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
```

But I'm getting a `Failed to create bus connection` error.

Traceback:

```
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
Warning in system("timedatectl", intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'timedatectl' had status 1
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
Warning in system("timedatectl", intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'timedatectl' had status 1
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
Warning in system("timedatectl", intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'timedatectl' had status 1
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (tidyverse)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpD1g9KP/downloaded_packages’
```

I've tried to install the dbus package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dbus
```

And am still getting the error after reboot.

I also tried:

```
sudo systemctl status
```

but it returns:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

Comment: It would appear that `systemd` is not installed or is not enabled.  Officially WSL1 or WSL2 do not yet support it.  This can be confirmed by running `sudo systemctl status`.  Have you installed `systemd-genie` which is the workaround to support `systemd` on WSL2?

Comment: @fpmurphy `sudo systemctl status` returns `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

Answer (score 3):

In .bashrc, or in some other alias file, add a variable for TZ. For me, I did

```
export TZ="America/New_York"
```

Then reload bash and it should recognize the timezone. You can see more about the timezone names here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Just a heads-up that this question is about Windows Subsystem for Linux - Are you running R under WSL?  I don't think this is likely to be the answer to this particular question on WSL.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I think any method that you can set environment variables would work. I am unfamiliar with WSL, but I'm not sure why you specifically think that WSL has some exception to this. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: It may work, but as I said "not likely" based on the way WSL works.  It could work if it suppresses R's attempt to use Systemd/`timedatectl`.  As mentioned in the comments, WSL doesn't support Systemd, so software that assumes that it is available will fail without additional configuration.

Comment: Or you also can add it to your  `.Renviron` file like `TZ="America/New_York"`

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming Debian system

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

## Modify TZ to whatever your timeozne is

TZ="Europe/Berlin" R -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'